# Elastcisearch avoid nested: TooManyClauses[maxClauseCount is set to 1024] error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Here I am using query like below :

> {
> "query": {
> "filtered": {
> "query": {
> "bool": {
> "must": [
> {
> "match_all": {}
> },
> {
> "bool": {
> "should": [
> {
> "bool": {
> "must": [
> {
> "match": {
> "board_id": {
> "query": "german",
> "operator": "and"
> }
> }
> }
> ]
> }
> [2000 more blocks]
> ]
> }
> },
> {
> "match": {
> "privacyLevel": {
> "query": "draft",
> "operator": "and"
> }
> }
> },
> {
> "match": {
> "is_root": {
> "query": "true",
> "operator": "and"
> }
> }
> }
> ]
> }
> },
> "filter": {
> "bool": {
> "must": {
> "terms": {
> "board_id": [
> "german",
> "firewall@tkb",
> "uc_ms_gateway_vxml_gw@tkb",
> "thd_carrier_management_processes",
> "baw_delivery@tkb",
> "uc_cucm_media_resources@tkb",
> "virtualization@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_a9k_sip_700_lc_thor_eng@tkb",
> "nx_os_pi_security_eng@tkb",
> "dutch",
> "content_reviews@tkb",
> "KH_test@tkb",
> "day_2_analytics@tkb",
> "ios_xe_transports_infraservices_eng",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs6k_infra_npu_driver@tkb",
> "cs-pi@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs4k_packet_qos@tkb",
> "tz_release_notes@tkb",
> "trex@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_asr9k_vsm_eng@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pi_policymgr_qos_eng@tkb",
> "ucc_ucce_mobile_agent@tkb",
> "Third_Party_Integration@tkb",
> "meeting_management_cmm@tkb",
> "spitfire_interfaces_triage@tkb",
> "direct_to_tower_methods",
> "context_service@tkb",
> "CCIE-Data-Center@tkb",
> "wireless_service_reference_guides@tkb",
> "cisco_webex_control_hub@tkb",
> "ios_xr_ios_spa_eng@tkb",
> "dc_auto_intelligent_automation_cloud@tkb",
> "industrial_network_director@tkb",
> "context_service_uccx@tkb",
> "cef-dev-1@tkb",
> "scratch_staging@tkb",
> "ask-ucs-pm-1@tkb",
> "server_virtualization@tkb",
> "ucsdirector@tkb",
> "cisco_prime_collaboration_provisioning@tkb",
> "Test_tkb",
> "relay_em7mom_tkb",
> "voice_and_speech_recognition@tkb",
> "sbsc_wireless@tkb",
> "dc_support_inspur_catalyst_1@tkb",
> "ios_isrg1_g2s@tkb",
> "ucc_ucca_rsm@tkb",
> "Board2@tkb",
> "test_board-12347@tkb",
> "as@tkb",
> "vxlan_evpn_discussion_board@tkb",
> "stealthwatch_installation_and_upgrades@tkb",
> "spitfire_span_eng@tkb",
> "cognitive_intelligence_cta@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs4k_infra_cctl@tkb",
> "sec_vpn_staging@tkb",
> "collaboration_webex_meetings_server@tkb",
> "sapphire_splunk_tkb",
> "esc_ultra_specific@tkb",
> "ces",
> "cloudsec_connector@tkb",
> "sss_asa_sfr_module_integration",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs4k_infra_envmon@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs6k_fwd_bundles@tkb",
> "csone@tkb",
> "ios_xe_policy_eng@tkb",
> "amp_private_cloud",
> "onprem@tkb",
> "duo@tkb",
> "collaboration_meetingplace_mp7xissues@tkb",
> "dfa@tkb",
> "dc_vxi_vdi_virtual_exp_infra@tkb",
> "msa_mrs_tkb",
> "uc_ms_qos@tkb",
> "compute_nova@tkb",
> "ios_ssh_eng@tkb",
> "big_data_broker@tkb",
> "4500_3700_3500_2960@tkb",
> "ofa_dpa_infra_de_eng@tkb",
> "nms_wireless_mse@tkb",
> "wea_broadband@tkb",
> "nx_ox_pi_eng@tkb",
> "sre_stakeholders",
> "SCA_issues@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pi_transports_eng@tkb",
> "tech_agnostic@tkb",
> "asa_firewall",
> "Policies-and-Identities@tkb",
> "packet_core_hardware@tkb",
> "Discussion_Board_Level2@tkb",
> "content_security_management_appliance",
> "productivity_tools@tkb",
> "UCSW@tkb",
> "context_aware_cx@tkb",
> "lansw_tech_port_interface@tkb",
> "dc_nexus5k_nexus5k2k@tkb",
> "virtualized_packet_core@tkb",
> "umts@tkb",
> "quicksilver_citrix@tkb",
> "wireless_assessments@tkb",
> "eng_packet_core_hardware@tkb",
> "virtual_application_cloud_segmentation_vacs_services@tkb",
> "dc_support_redhat_redhat@tkb",
> "sec_csm_staging@tkb",
> "problem_tracker",
> "network_insights@tkb",
> "thd_change_discussion@tkb",
> "ucc_ucca_mediasense@tkb",
> "ariba-db-connector@tkb",
> "cisco_security_awareness_tkb",
> "classic_ios_isr_serial_eng@tkb",
> "uc_ma_Cisco_Prime_Collaboration_and_Other@tkb",
> "stub_articles",
> "emerging_platforms@tkb",
> "Hardware_Relate@tkb",
> "Topic@tkb",
> "sre_high_level",
> "ios_xr_asr9k_ether_ea_bundles_pd_eng@tkb",
> "ExternalURLModeration_Archival_forum@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs6k_infra_cpu@tkb",
> "cmcs@tkb",
> "9000@tkb",
> "cisco_design_certifications@tkb",
> "cmcs_discussions@tkb",
> "memory_component_issue@tkb",
> "dc_mds_hardware@tkb",
> "collaboration_meetingplace_mpe@tkb",
> "XR_TC2E_Training@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs4k_infra_bp_driver@tkb",
> "cloudsec_web_filtering@tkb",
> "agile_scrum@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs5500_bootloader_db@tkb",
> "security_car@tkb",
> "omd_db@tkb",
> "cco-team-1@tkb",
> "database_tkb",
> "docker_containers@tkb",
> "webex_calling_formerly_spark_call@tkb",
> "Investigations@tkb",
> "smart_account_and_licensing_glo@tkb",
> "virtualized_voice_browser@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs6k_infra_ccc@tkb",
> "ucce_live_data@tkb",
> "psrr_ios_xr@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_srv6_eng@tkb",
> "Tools_Automation@tkb",
> "mantl@tkb",
> "vds_tv@tkb",
> "firex-reports-1@tkb",
> "chinese-tac-1@tkb",
> "nxos-urib-dev-1@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_ncs6k_fwd_ucode@tkb",
> "one_csdn@tkb",
> "cisco_webex_teams@tkb",
> "6500-tme@tkb",
> "firex-reports@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_asr9k_platform_manager_eng@tkb",
> "trackers@tkb",
> "cisco_software_manager_eng@tkb",
> "Test_Board@tkb",
> "rms@tkb",
> "vxlan_evpn_ansible@tkb",
> "web-help-1@tkb",
> "umbrella",
> "dc_sap_app_bwa@tkb",
> "vWSA@tkb",
> "rca_ts",
> "ios_xr_pd_crs_forward_multicast@tkb",
> "ncs_540_eng@tkb",
> "lancope_pilot@tkb",
> "situation_manager@tkb",
> "netsim@tkb",
> "security_acs@tkb",
> "ios_xr_pd_sf_fpd_db@tkb",
> "rms_discussions@tkb",
> "fwsm@tkb"
> ]
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }
> }

Can we optimize it further so that the error can be avoided.

Comment: The `filtered` query hints that you're using a very old version of Elasticsearch, probably 2.x. Any chance to upgrade since there have been SO many enhancements since?

Comment: yes I am using 1.7, upgrade is on plan. But currently I need to fix this. Is there a way That the query can be optimised to remove the error?

Comment: If I understand right, you have a terms query on `board_id` as a filter with many values and also one match query on `board_id` for the same terms?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should upgrade as soon as possible, 1.7 has been EOL since at least 2018. Upgrading directly won't be possible, though, you'll probably be better off reindexing your data into a more recent versions, ideally the latest one.

Concerning your issue, you can "solve" it by modifying the following setting on your index and set it to a value high enough that will make the error disappear:

```
PUT your-index/_settings
{
  "index.query.bool.max_clause_count": 2000
}
```

You can also set it in the cluster settings to be applied on all new indexes:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "indices.query.bool.max_clause_count": 2000
  }
}
```

You need to know that there's a reason why this setting defaults to 1024 and increasing it can have other undesired consequences on your cluster. So you should proceed with care and carefully monitor your cluster as you increase this value.

Comment: any luck with this?